# Bind the result of list.contains() method

Tags: java, binding, javafx, javafx-8

I want to bind text field to indicate whether list of integer contain 1.
i have a button that insert 1 to the list and I want the text field will update but this doesn't happens. why and how can i repair it?

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            list.add(1);
        }
    });
    TextField txt = new TextField();
    txt.textProperty().bind(new SimpleStringProperty(String.valueOf(list.contains(1))));
    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().addAll(btn,txt);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're binding the `SimpleStringProperty` to the actual String rather than the value of the list. That String is never updated since `String.valueOf()` returns a new String object.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a BooleanBinding:

```
@Override
public void start( final Stage primaryStage )
{

    primaryStage.setTitle( "Hello World!" );
    final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // we need an ObservableList, duh, to observe!
    final ObservableList<Integer> oblist = FXCollections.observableArrayList( list );
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText( "Say 'Hello World'" );
    btn.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle( ActionEvent event )
        {
            oblist.add( 1 );
        }
    } );
    BooleanBinding bb = Bindings.createBooleanBinding( () -> oblist.contains( 1 ), oblist );

    TextField txt = new TextField();
    txt.textProperty().bind( bb.asString() );
    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().addAll( btn, txt );

    final Scene scene = new Scene( root, 400, 300 );
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

> I still doesn't understand what problem with my code, can you explain
>   me please?

Let's break down the code: `new SimpleStringProperty(String.valueOf(list.contains(1)));`

-> initially `list.contains(1)` = false
-> `String.valueOf(false)` = "false"
-> `new SimpleStringProperty("false")` will create new instance of `StringProperty` with initial value "false", and this instance is bound to textProperty of textField. That is it, since we are initiating with the **String** value "false", no further observation for `list` and its content where it contains 1 or not. Hence we need an observable list here.

Thus the textfield's text will change in sync if the bound StringProperty is changed. Rewriting as,

```
StringProperty sp = new SimpleStringProperty(String.valueOf(list.contains(1)));
txt.textProperty().bind(sp);
sp.set("newVal"); // at this point textfield's text will be updated with 
// "newVal", but it has nothing about list and its content.
```

Comment: thank you. it's work! but I still doesn't understand what problem with my code, can you explain me please?

Comment: thank you. and if I change the list to observeablelist in my original code is it works?

Comment: my question is - in order to bind to condition i must use boolean binding? another question - we i read about my problem i saw that binding is lazy so it's update when there's access to the value. so what here it's work?

Comment: @user3508607, 1) if you had tried you would see it will not worked. 2) Ask it in new question thread.